# How would I create the visual equivalent of a UIView in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, list, swiftui

Here is my code for my `List` items in my project using SwiftUI.

```
struct ServicesListItem: View {

    var title: String
    var description: String
    var colorHex: String
    var imageName: String

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(imageName)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {

                Text(title)
                    .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .black, design: .rounded))
                    .foregroundColor(Color(hex: colorHex))

                Text(description)
                    .font(.system(size: 10, weight: .medium, design: .rounded))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
            }
            .frame(height: 60)
        }
    }
}
```

I want to put all of the elements of each `ServicesListItem` inside another "view" and add padding on all sides to give the appearance that the contents of each item are inside a raised view rather than the edge-to-edge look of the `List`. I've done this easily with UIKit by using a UIView as a parent view inside of a UITableViewCell. haven't found a means of doing this yet with SwiftUI. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## SwiftUI 1.0

Hi Austin, here are a couple of relevant changes I made to your list item view:

- Moved the frame to the HStack level
- Made HStack fill width of device with `.maxWidth: .infinity`
- Added a solid background color that you can then add a shadow to for the "raised look"

### Code

```
struct ServicesListItem: View {
    var title: String
    var description: String
    var colorHex: String
    var imageName: String
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(imageName)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
                Text(title)
                    .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .black, design: .rounded))
                    .foregroundColor(Color(hex: colorHex))
                
                Text(description)
                    .font(.system(size: 10, weight: .medium, design: .rounded))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
            }
        }
        // Set the size of entire row. maxWidth makes it take up whole width of device.
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 60, alignment: .leading)
        .padding(10) // Spacing around all the contents
        // Add a solid colored background that you can put a shadow on
        // (corner radius optional)
        .background(Color.white.cornerRadius(5).shadow(radius: 3))
    }
}
```

### Example

[image: Screenshot Example]

Is this similar to what you were thinking?

(As of SwiftUI 1.0, we don't know how to remove the lines. ☹️)